# how to run a Python project repository properly using Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

As a terrible rookie, I'm trying to run code from this repository https://github.com/wtomin/SteerablePyramid_Torch_TF_Numpy

Since terminal is not very user friendly, I thought Anaconda+Jupyter Notebooks would be the most easy to use approach for me. I followed the installation instructions given in the repository readme in a new Jupyter notebook. And now I'm simply trying to run some code from the project but getting "not found" errors:

1. When I go the examples folder and try `!python example_tf.py`, it gives the following error:

> FileNotFoundError: Image file not found on disk: ./assets/patagonia.jpg

but the directory and the file actually exist

2. Instead when I try to copy and run the code within example_tf.py, it finds error in line `from steerable.SCFpyr_TF import SCFpyr_TF` by outputting the following

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'steerable'

but SCFpyr_TF.py exists under the folder steerable

No idea why the files are not found after I did the installation as instructed. Why can't the Jupyter notebook see those other files in other relevant directories of the project?

I must be doing some horrible rookie mistakes. Can someone please give a step-by-step instructions of running a python project downloaded from a github repository properly using a Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Presumably your working directory and Python's `PATH` aren't configured according to the expectation of the code you're trying to use.

Comment: Just an FYI as it isn't going to help your path issue, for running a script inside a Jupyter notebook, there's a magic command that is more full-featured. So instead of `!python example_tf.py`, you'd use `%run example_tf.py`. In general, the notebook handles the output better that way. Plus `%run` has more abilities related to notebook. One that especially nice is the `-i` flag that runs the script in the same namespace as the notebook so you can define variables in the notebook and they'll be used in the script, if not clobbered by anything in the script itself. This is very helpful for ...

Comment: <continued> development or when using the notebook to guide the user through setting up a 'configuration' before kicking off a script that does the bulk of the 'real' work. By putting the script separate there's less of a chance the user will mess up the code playing around in the notebook.

Comment: As for your real question, there's no one way to do what you are asking. As Sam Mason is trying to steer you towards realizing, you have inspect things and adjust. A lot of people assume that you git cloned the entire repository and then cd'd into it to work. But that isn't universal at all. The best are those that include configuration files that allow it to be run in a remote session served by the 'mybinder'. Example: Go [here](https://github.com/ismms-himc/clustergrammer2-notebooks) and press `launch binder`. After the temporary session spins up on the remote machine, you can click on ...

Comment: <conintued> the notebooks directory and start with running notebook 1.0 and it should work. You'll notice that it matches what they expect because it even uses relative paths under 'Load Dataset' in notebook 1.0. The configuration file insured that the environment was set up right when the session started. But you have to run such configuration steps if you are working locally and not all repos include much guidance so that sometimes you stumble installing as you keep hitting things missing.

Comment: In the script you reference [here 'example_tf.py'](https://github.com/wtomin/SteerablePyramid_Torch_TF_Numpy/blob/master/examples/example_tf.py), they have ` default='./assets/patagonia.jpg'` . So that tells you they expect the script to be copied out to the same directory level as where assets is stored, which is the root directory when cloning https://github.com/wtomin/SteerablePyramid_Torch_TF_Numpy. They probably just developed all the examples at the root directory and then made an `examples` folder later and shoved them in there to not clutter root. (Guessing based on only that one.)

Comment: <continued> I suspect if you move the scripts out of `examples` and into the root directory, they'll work. For example with `example_tf.py`, it shouldn't error on the line `from steerable.SCFpyr_TF import SCFpyr_TF` now because it's on the same level as the `steerable` directory and can import that module now. Ideally, in the repo or associated documentation, they would have stated, "If you'd like to run the examples, copy them into root and execute... ." (And maybe they have; I didn't look too hard.) However, often a little bushwhacking is too be expected.

Comment: All that is a roundabout way to say the root directory of the project is always a good guess, but not universal. In a parallel universe, the developers there may have already adjusted the examples to work from the `examples` directory and expect you to have installed `steerable` as a module using [setup.py for it](https://github.com/wtomin/SteerablePyramid_Torch_TF_Numpy/blob/master/setup.py) in root, see [here for example](https://kb.iu.edu/d/acey#setup).

Comment: Indeed, if I open a session using https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/wtomin/SteerablePyramid_Torch_TF_Numpy/HEAD., (after repeating in parallel what you initially described and hitting the assets path issue), I can get farther than you got by executing in a notebook `%pip install scikit-image;%conda install torchvision -c pytorch;%pip install opencv-python;!cp examples/* .;%run example_tf.py` where each command separated by a semi-colon was in a separate cell. (Note that ideally I wouldn't be mixing and matching conda and pip but I just was hacking around to test if it worked.)

Comment: Also note that in the course of making the image that gets run mybinder when you click the link I provided above, the `setup.py` script gets run (along with the other stuff in requirements.txt`) and so even in a notebook opened in `examples` , you can run. `from steerable.SCFpyr_TF import SCFpyr_TF` in a cell and it will work. That is because it was installed properly via `setup.py` and you don't have to rely on the directory hierarchy alone to have Python see it in the relative path. I suspect that step didn't necessarily need to be run if I was running in root, but I didn't test that 100%.

Comment: <continued> Actually the fact I had to install additional stuff to even get that point tells me they didn't do a thorough job documenting the environment in what they put in the repo. ( I have up after hiting a hardware issue that I could fix on MyBinder via forking and further configuring; howerver, the default attempt served well enough for the illustration.)